# Simple .htaccess RewriteRule not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Not sure why this isn't working:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+ http://example.com [L]
```

The `RewriteCond` is working as far as I can tell.

To me, the `RewriteRule` reads:

- `^` Start the match
- `.+` One or more characters

Yet, *Firefox 44* is telling me

> **The page isn't redirecting properly**
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.

If the `RewriteRule` started with `^.*`, I would expect the server to be caught in an endless loop.

But `^.+` ought to work, no?

Comment: This is because example.com is redirecting to example.com

Comment: Agreed. But that's what you'd expect with `^.*` isn't it? Why is it happening with `^.+`?

Comment: No, the condition is making it so.

Comment: Ah, okay. So how can I state _one or more characters_ (not _zero or more characters_)?

Comment: That's exactly what your rule does, but the condition says that the rewrite must occur if the domain ends in `example.com` **and**, per the rule, there is one more more character in the request URI. What is the purpose of this anyway?

Comment: I am setting up a small site for a non-profit group which has no budget for webspace. Their domain provider allows me to give their domain a masked redirect to pages on my webspace via an iframe. External links to http://masked-domain.org/any-page/ will (obviously) fail, so I need to redirect any request (except for the parent domain) back to the parent domain. I don't know if there is an alternative approach but I am happy to hear suggestions. As it is, it's not ideal for usability, but the site is small enough that any other pages will only ever be a single click away from the main page.

Comment: You rule is working fine on the first Rewrite iteration . example.com/foo => example.com/foo. But It fails on the second rewrite cycle and rewrites the target url to itself.

Comment: Not following 100%. So the group has the domain, but no hosting, and so you're pointing the domain to your server? If that is the case, are you not able to simply set a document root for thir domain? (Forgive me if I've misunderstood.)

Comment: Yes, you've understood correctly. Yes, quite possibly I might well be able to set a document root for their domain. If you can explain it in an answer below I shall be very grateful and upvote. My field is `HTML5`, `CSS3` & `Javascript`. Regarding `.htaccess` and server configuration, I'm still very much on a learning curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You re getting redirect loop due to `DirectoryIndex` handler being added in REQUEST_URI.

To fix this issue you can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.localhost$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+ http://www.localhost [L,R]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\. [NC]` will stop redirect loop since `/index.html` or `/index.php` is usually the `DirectoryIndex` handler.

Comment: That's insanely good knowledge, @anubhava. One to remember. Thank you very much indeed.